# Applying for EB-1B visa when my parent company has 3 full time researchers

Tags: usa, immigration

I finished my Ph.D. last year and am currently working as a full-time researcher at a company. I have 10+ publications and am currently part of the program committee for a conference.

One qualification for an EB-1B visa is that the employer must have at least 3 full-time researchers. My company doesn't have 3 full-time researchers. But its parent company has more than 3 full-time researchers. Am I eligible for the EB-1B green card application?

Comment: Where are you getting the idea that there's a 3 (or other) person limit of researchers per company?

Comment: @mkennedy Possibly from the evidence stated here as required for the category ‘Outstanding professors and researchers’ https://www.uscis.gov/working-in-the-united-states/permanent-workers/employment-based-immigration-first-preference-eb-1?

Comment: @Traveller Ah, I see. Thank you for pointing it out. I added that info to the question.